# Difference between Gateaux and Fréchet derivative

Tags: frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

Suppose I have the operator

$$T:L_2[0,1]\to L_2[0,1],$$
$$T[x(t)] = \sin(x(t)).$$
My first question: Is it true that the Gateaux derivative of this operator equals to the ordinary derivative of $\sin(x(t))$? And how can I show that this operator does not have a Fréchet derivative anywhere?

Let's take some $h \in L_2[0,1]$ and compute  the directional derivative with respect to $h.$ Then we get something like

$$\cos(x(t))\lim_{\ell\to0} \frac{\sin(\ell h(t))}{\ell}.$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Since $x$ is only square integrable, $\sin\circ x$ may not even be differentiable

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please look through it?

Comment: Well observe that $$\frac{\sin(\ell h(t))}{\ell}=\frac{\sin(\ell h(t))}{\ell h(t)}h(t)\to h(t)$$as $\ell\to0$

Comment: Thank you! So I computed Gateaux derivative which is $T^{'}[x(t)](h) = cos(x(t))h$, to show that T doesnt have Frechet derivative I need to disprove that $T^{'}$ is  
  continious?

Comment: The Gateaux derivative is correct, but you need to take the limit in the definition in $L^2[0,1]$ and not just pointwise. This can easily be fixed with the DCT though

Comment: Furthermore, the Gateaux derivative you get at each point *is* continuous as it is a bounded linear operator by $$\lVert T'[x]h\rVert_{L^2[0,1]}=\sqrt{\int_0^1(\cos(x(t))h(t))^2~\mathrm{d}t}\leq\sqrt{\int_0^1 h(t)^2~\mathrm{d}t}=\lVert h\rVert_{L^2[0,1]}.$$